# Trigger for non User changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm creating an alert for maintenance, so whenever the component reach the limit of cycles it shows a message and send an email advising that the requisition for the component is required,let me explain the problem.
I'm currently using an import range to read the number of cycles of another spreadsheet that gets upgraded every week, Since I am not entering the data for the cycles, I'm just using the import range to SUM them in my own  spreadsheet, the problem comes within the trigger itself, I want to send the mail every week with the status, but since I'am not modifying anything directly, the trigger onEdit does not detect when the external spreadsheet updates the data, neither can use Onchange again, since I am not modifying anything on the spreadsheet, I used onOpen to test, and worked, but that's not the point for automating.

The code itself works fine is just the trigger that I cannot found a way to replace it
here is the code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet9");   
 Limite = "5800000";
 Atencion = "5000000"
 Estacion = ""; // ciclos actuales
 SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID = "1TL3r3fmibj1vkIJIQ-h6FddNGDtCR6frTinYawepbD4"
 NAME_COL_INDEX = 8; //pruebo con 100
 var cell1 = s.getRange('E6');
 var value1 = cell1.getValue();
 var value2 = Limite;
 var value3 = Atencion;
//https://cdn-icons.flaticon.com/png/512/520/premium/520464.png?token=exp=1655414676~hmac=998c7f21eb0b42271a6e81027891a121
// preguntar con maricela para haecr pedido automatico 
//https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/344/smiling.png
 if (value1<value3){  
 
 var html = `
 <center><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/166/166519.png" /></center>
 <p class="body" style="font-family: comfortaa; color:gray; font-size: 30px; text-align:center">
 Aun no se ha llegado al limite de ciclos para remplazo </p>
 `
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(550)
     .setHeight(640);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, '⚙️ Vida Util Activa ');
 }
 else if (value1>value3 && value1<value2){
   //esnviar Email con alerta proxima
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet9").getRange("B2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your Alert email! MLS MAINTENANCE SUPPLY '; // Second column
var subject = 'PRUEBA PARA REALIZAR ALERTA';
   var html = `
 <center><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/166/166561.png" /></center>
 <p class="body" style="font-family: comfortaa; color:gray; font-size: 30px; text-align:center">
 Se acerca al limite de ciclos, Por favor contemple realizar pronto el remplazo </p>
 `
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(550)
     .setHeight(640);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, '⚙️⚠️  Vida Util por Acabar ⚠️ ');
 GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
 }else if (value1>=value2){
   var html = `
 <center><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/166/166563.png" /></center>
 <p class="body" style="font-family: comfortaa; color:gray; font-size: 30px; text-align:center">
 Por favor realice pronto el plan de accion para el remplazo </p>
 `
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(550)
     .setHeight(640);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, '⚙️   Vida Util esta al Limite ');
 }
}
```

Comment: Time based trigger?

Comment: Neither working, I don't know the reason, it executes but doesnt send the email

Comment: `"I want to send the mail every week"` sounds like you should be using a trigger that executes this code on a time-basis and nothing else. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeUzG.png) If you have tried this and it does not work to send the email, you should look at your current code for errors.